# Can't Post "Value" From Radio Button to Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

Created a form that uses radio buttons, but I was unable to post the value to the **SponsorRegistration** table.

The 5 columns of the table are named *Breakfast*, *Lunch*, *Dinner*, *Supper* and *Dessert*.

When a customer selects *Breakfast* and click Submit, a "Y" (Yes) should be posted under the specific column but this is not the case for me.

The **SponsorAmount** table contains the amount of money sponsored for each meal.  I think there should be a "if" and "elseif" statements for these radio buttons but I don't know how to incorporate to make it work.

**HTML**

```
''''BUILD RECORDSET CONNECTION STATIC
Set OnAmount = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQLStrAmount = "SELECT * FROM SponsorAmount"
OnAmount.Open SQLStrAmount, Connect, adOpenStatic

breakfastValue = OnAmount("Breakfast")
lunchValue = OnAmount("Lunch")
goldValue = OnAmount("Gold")
diamondValue = OnAmount("Diamond")
platinumValue = OnAmount("Platinum")

''''CLOSE RECORDSET CONNECTION
OnAmount.Close
Set OnAmount = nothing

    <form method="post" action="SponsorPost.asp" onSubmit="return submitIt(this)">
        <input type="radio" name="sponsorlevelValue" value='breakfastValue' checked='checked'><b>Breakfast</b>

        <input type="radio" name="sponsorlevelValue" value='lunchValue' checked='checked'><b>Lunch</b>

        <input type="radio" name="sponsorlevelValue" value='dinnerValue' checked='checked'><b>Dinner</b>

        <input type="radio" name="sponsorlevelValue" value='supperValue' checked='checked'><b>Supper</b>

        <input type="radio" name="sponsorlevelValue" value='dessertValue' checked='checked'><b>Dessert</b>

    </form>
```

Here is the "**SponsorPost.asp**" page.  Except for the **sponsorlevelValue**, all the other Values get stored in the database.

```
<%
peopleVal = Request("peopleValue")
meetingVal = Request("meetingValue")
sponsorlevelVal = Request("sponsorlevelValue")
paymentTypeVal = Request("paymentTypeValue")
giftVal = Request("giftValue")
itemVal = Request("itemValue")

''''BUILD DATABASE CONNECTION
Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Data Source=XXXXXX; Initial Catalog=XXX; User ID=XXX; Password=XXX"

''''BUILD RECORDSET CONNECTION STATIC
Set OnRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM SponsorRegistration WHERE Deleted='N'"
OnRS.Open SQLStr, Connect,  adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

OnRS.AddNew
OnRS("PeopleIDNum") = CLng(peopleVal)
OnRS("MeetingIDNum") = CLng(meetingVal)
OnRS("RegistrationDate") = tDate
OnRS("PaymentTypeIDNum") = CLng(paymentTypeVal)
OnRS("Gift") = giftVal
OnRS("Item") = itemVal
OnRS("Paid") = "N"
OnRS("Deleted") = "N"
OnRS.Update

''''CLOSE RECORDSET CONNECTION
OnRS.Close
Set OnRS = nothing

''''CLOSE DATABASE CONNECTION
Connect.Close
Set Connect = nothing
%>
```

Comment: This is much easier to read.  Thank you Juhana.

Comment: There's a code button that you can use to format the question so that the tags get shown correctly. It looks like this: `{}`

Comment: Juhana, can you kindly help me with my problem?  Thanks.

Comment: first you can't have all radios checked, it's against the behaivor of the radios. if that you want is to have more than 1 value selected at the same time, then use checkboxes instead. second with only this fragment of code we can't see your problem. post more code that involves your problem not only the HTML part of it

Comment: Rafael, I only want 1 value selected at a time.  By the way, do I post my codes via the "edit" button?

Comment: @Esther: why don't you just write down the error message or the outcome ? For example, you can tell us what you end up getting in the html and in the db. Also, please cut down the code you post -  eliminating the areas that may have nothing to do with the issue. With less and more relavant code. I think we can solve your problem much more efficiently. I know we can solve this problem easily for you if you follow what I'm saying.

Comment: i have one question how do you determine (with which data) the radio button that must be selected ... ?

Comment: @John: Pardon me, I'm not quite good with tech terms.  To answer your question, there is no error message.  After the "Submit" button is clicked, I can see all the values stored in the db for other buttons (other questions asked), but not for the question asked if sponsor is donating breakfast, lunch, or ...  You see, the SponsorRegistration table consists of these columns "includesbreakfast", "includeslunch", and so on.  What I want is to post the value 'Y' under the correct column/row after the sponsor selected a button and post his choice.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'On SponsorPost.asp, plug this code right before the OnRS.Update

select case true
case sponsorlevelVal = "breakfastValue"
    OnRS("Breakfast") = "Y"
case sponsorlevelVal = "lunchValue"
    OnRS("Lunch") = "Y"
case sponsorlevelVal = "dinnerValue"
    OnRS("Gold") = "Y"
case sponsorlevelVal = "supperValue"
    OnRS("Diamond") = "Y"
case sponsorlevelVal = "dessertValue"
    OnRS("Platinum") = "Y"
case else
    response.write "sponsorlevelVal has not been passed. warn the user"
    response.end
end select
```

Comment: @esther  you are welcome. don't forget to check the accepted answer. Click on the gray OK sign to make it green. Accepting answers improve your chances of getting answers for your next questions. People tend to answer only those people who accept answers. That's the way stackoverflow works.

Comment: I checked the "check" symbol for this answer to accept.  Hope I did it correctly.  It's nice to get some directions on how stackoverflow works.

Comment: Thank you @Esther. When you get a chance, take a look at this page as to [how stackoverflow works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove the checked attribute on all the radio buttons.

And then check what value you see when you do this

```
Response.write request("sponsorlevelValue")
```

you should be seing something like

```
dinnerValue
```

Once you verify that, we can then move on to the next step. The rest will become simple.

But you must first remove the "checked" word from the html.

Comment: I put a Response.Write(Request("sponsorlevelValue") and I did receive breakfastValue back.  The "checked" words have been deleted.